# Cannot find symbol, Error message when overriding constructor! Superclass variables are public

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, subclass, superclass

I'm having the error "Cannot find symbol" and is referring me to create the variable I am attempting to use from my superclass in my subclass even though I have the variable set to public. My goal with this code is to take two parameters in my subclass being "productName" and "quantity" and pass them to my superclass and assign them to the relevant variables. I also need to pass the value of "DISCOUNT" to the superclass variable "discount".

Any help on this problem would be greatly appreciated.

My superclass code containing the variables and relevant constructors is below.

```
public class Order1 {

public String productName;
private double price;
public int discount;
public int quantity;
private double total;
private String message;
private boolean isDiscounted;
private boolean isValidOrder;
private static int orderNum = 0


public Order1() {
    // sets validity to false, sets message, increments orderNum by 1
    isValidOrder = false;
    message = "**ERROR**: Order number cannot be totalled as no details have  been supplied";
    orderNum = orderNum + 1;
}

public final void Order1(String productName, int quantity) {
    // sets productName variable to productName parameter value
    this.productName = productName;
    testQuantity(quantity);
}

public Order1(String productName) {
    // sets productName variable to productName parameter value
    this.productName = productName;

}
```

The folowing code is my subclass

```
package Order;

/**
 *
* @author Aurya
*/
public class InternalOrder extends Order1 {
    private final static double DISCOUNT;

    public InternalOrder(double DISCOUNT) {
        super(productName, quantity, discount);
        DISCOUNT = .40;
        this.discount = DISCOUNT;
        this.productName = productName;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

}
```

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above answers already point out your problem in the constructor.  If I understand your code correctly, you want to apply a fixed discount (40%) to all internal orders.

Firstly, you can assign a value to `discount` variable directly in your constructor.

```
this.discount = 0.4;
```

Secondly, if you want the superclass variables to be accessible by your subclasses, it's better to use `protected` than `public`.

Your `InternalOrder` class should look something like this:

```
public class InternalOrder extends Order1 {

    public InternalOrder() {
        super(productName, quantity);
        this.discount = 0.4;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> super(productName, quantity, discount);

is wrong because it wants to call a constructor with 3 parameters, which does not exist into Order1. Get rid of "discount"

> DISCOUNT = .40;

Does not make sense. You modify the constructor parameter (already weird), even before to get its value.

> this.productName = productName;
>   this.quantity = quantity;

The "this" is useless because there is not other variables with the same name into the function. So in reality you're doing "productName = productName;" and "quantity = quantity;". If "super" is correctly used, they will be useless.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `Order1` constructor with 3 parameters.
You're trying to invoke a constructor in class `Order1` which is not present. Create a three parameter constructor in the `Order1` class :

```
public Order1(productName, quantity, discount)
```